# How can I reverse a string

Tags: python

I've made a program which reverses the given word. It goes like that:

```
word = input("Type text: ")
x = len(word)
y = x - 1

while y >= 0:
   print(word[y])
   y -= 1
```

Naturally loop prints each letter in separate line and I have no idea how to combine those letters into one string. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use `word[::-1]` to reverse the string. This uses python's list slice method to step through the string with a step of -1.

Comment: Thanks, that will save me a lot of effort in the future.

Comment: @DanielLewandowski If you code something in python for a relatively simple task and end up feeling like there might be a better way to do it - don't be afraid to Google what you're trying to do to see if that way exists

Answer (score 0):

add a comma after the print

```
print(word[y]),
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
reversed = ''.join([word[len(word) - count] for count in range(1,len(word)+1)])
```

(replace range with xrange for Python 2)

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a list and then use `join`. Like this:

```
word = input("Type text: ")
x = len(word)
y = x - 1
store_1 = []
while y >= 0:
   store_1.append(word[y])
   y -= 1
together = ''.join(store_1)
print(together)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many way to revers the string in your code whatever you done is correct but, in print command if you are using python 3 you have to write this

```
print(word[y], end="")  
# if you are using python 2 then,
# print word,
# you can also try this 
word = (input("Enter String"))[::-1] # if input is abcd 
print(word) # output is dcba
```